# What was the point of collecting ectoplasm?

Tags: lockwood-and-co

We know that certain groups have been collecting ectoplasm from ghosts on the Other Side. Originally, Lucy’s hypothesis about this was that

> Marissa Fittes consumed it to stay young.

However, it was later revealed that, although this was Fittes’s original plan, she had moved on to the simpler expedient of possession.

So why was Marissa, or her followers in the Orpheus society, collecting ectoplasm in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To increase her spiritual power

It seems that, initially, the ectoplasm *was* a component of her immortality:

> “I soon discovered that Ezekiel was right—by absorbing the essence I
> did replenish my own strength. And my spirit grew powerful.” Her black
> eyes searched mine. “But there was a catch!”
>
> <sub>*The Empty Grave*</sub>

Although it is not explicitly stated, it’s implied that this "strength" was what allowed her to become strong enough to possess Penelope.

> “A mortal body always fails you. A mortal body always lets you down.
> But if your spirit is sufficiently strong…” She touched my face with
> her ice-cold hand and stepped away. “There are other options.”
>
> <sub>*The Empty Grave*</sub>

The further collection is presumably for the experiments of the Orpheus Society, who sought to continue Marissa’s work. It seems unlikely that Marissa continues to need it, now that she already possesses Penelope’s body. But perhaps she does need it to maintain her strength, as well.